# Android app reaches API, but token not sent back to Android

Tags: c#, api, rest, xamarin.android, missingmethodexception

I am having an issue where my Android app reaches an API that has a token, but the token is not getting sent back to the app. I get the error:

*System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type System.string*

I am using Xamarin.Android (C#). I'm trying to add a method to my Android/DataUtility.cs that calls an REST WebAPI method that returns a token. The token is not coming back to Android. What am I missing?

I've tried breakpoints, stepping through, multiple alterations of the URL, postman, async and non async methods, tasks, etc. I've tried searching on this as well as the error above.

```
public async void startVisit(VisitDetailsResponse visit)
{
    myClient = new FM.LiveSwitch.Client(SettingsValues.GatewayURL, appID);
    Register();
}

public void Register()
{
    var RegURL = "/GetLSRegisterToken?wsUserID=" + myClient.UserId + "&wsDeviceID=" + myClient.DeviceId + "&wsID=" + myClient.Id + "&channelName=" + channelName;
    var registerToken = DataUtility.GetLiveSwitchTokenResponseAsync(SettingsValues.ApiURLValue, RegURL).Result;
}
```

[image: AndroidToAPI]

It does get to WebAPI, which has a token(screenshot below), but it never gets back to the return statement in DataUtility (line 427 in screenshot above)
(Note: I can call the WebAPI method and return a value successfully from Postman)

[image: WebApi Token]

It ends up here in Android/ApiUtility
[image: Android Error]

and then:
[image: Default Constructor error]

Comment: I tried the code you provided. But I could not reproduce this issue. Could you provide more details to reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by placing it inside async Task:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var RegURL = "/GetLSRegisterToken?wsUserID=" + myClient.UserId + "&wsDeviceID=" + myClient.DeviceId + "&wsID=" + myClient.Id + "&channelName=" + channelName;
    var registerToken = DataUtility.GetLiveSwitchTokenResponseAsync(SettingsValues.ApiURLValue, RegURL).Result;
});
```